# LiPo/Li-Ion Cells in series max end-to-end voltage

Tags: high-voltage, series, batteries

I have wondered how many cells can be connected in series before issues may arise. I also wonder what specifications on the tech data sheet would allow you to decide which batteries are best for high voltages series?

My current understanding is that even though the end to end voltage may be high in a series of cells the voltage across a single cell will only be that cells voltage?

Other thoughts about the eventual mode of failure? Insulation? Shorting?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Or are you simply curious about what would happen?

Comment: Its a curiosity really. I always thought their would be something in the tech data that would indicate the max end voltage that the cell is capable. I also wonder if I just have an understanding that is incorrect. Even though I would not actually physically create anything as high voltage the high voltage(~500v) battery fed inverter driven AC motor in the Tesla interests me. Initially I would not have thought that the cells would be capable of such voltage which is where the learning started(A long while back). Doesn't seem like anyone really addresses it so thus the curiosity and this Q.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues, the most important are personal safety, and the safety of the cells.

Most people think of batteries as 'safe', and may be less careful around them than with mains electricity. Different authorities across the globe have slightly different voltages for when low voltage stops being 'safe', but all pick a voltage in the range 40v to 60v.

Many applications manage this problem by building cells into 48v batteries, which are relatively safe to handle, service, replace, and then connecting those in series if they need higher voltage.

When you build cells into a battery, some battery chemistries like lead acid are sufficiently tolerant of cell voltage that you can infer cell voltage from battery voltage. Similarly NimH, but to a lesser extent. Lithium chemistries are totally intolerant of this, any lithium battery of any size needs individual cell monitoring. So given that you must monitor the voltage of all cells, the complexity of the monitoring circuit becomes a practical issue. It's relatively straightforward to buy or design monitoring that copes with 48v batteries.

It goes without saying that any cells connected to make a battery should be of the same type and manufacturer, state (ideally new) and state of charge.

Once you have a battery, you have the potential difference between the casings of cells to consider. This will rarely be a problem in normal operation, but the robustness of insulation may be the difference between an accident being inconvenient, and causing fire, explosion or loss of life. Another good reason to keep the end to end battery voltage lower rather than higher.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting cells in series you should **guarantee** that they are the same capacity and age (in practice, the best you can get is: they have similar capacity and age) **ALSO** when charging or discharging **no cell** must be allowed to go outside of the acceptable temperature and voltage limits. This means each cell will have to be monitored individually !

There are ICs that are suited for this purpose. You will find them in battery packs for laptops for example as these often have 3 to 4 (clusters of) cells in series.

Lead-Acid batteries are not so picky/dangerous so for them these safety precautions are usually not needed.

So it is not that there are certain Lithium based cells that are more suited to place in series. All of them are suited as long as you monitor them individually for voltage and temperature. Perhaps that is one of the lessons Boeing learned when the batteries of their 787 had issues.